# Pouchdb giving ReferenceError: t is not defined for map/reduce queries

Tags: pouchdb

I have a map reduce design doc in my DB. However when I run any query on it it gives me error  `ReferenceError: t is not defined`.
I managed to debug this issue and found following area in where this issue is happening in pouchdb code.

[image]

[image]

The doc which is trying to be map/reduce is this:

```json
{"uid":"03b72b1c690abacd70ec6a9690ad763a","type":"purchase","order":[{"plan_name":"50000 SMS","sms_count":50000,"active":true,"price":6000,"_id":"7ed7a9474ed051d6296afe966b97bf43","_rev":"1-261f6278bd0eccccfb1785f4d1613619"}],"total_price":6000,"total_sms":50000,"date":1610105466674,"_id":"e9b06cd8cfade9d62d6676c8f3bff806","_rev":"1-6806dc8e13bcc53e8eb8d349c54acd78"}
```

And my design doc has been:

```
{
    _id:"_design/for_orders",
    views:{
        find_total_sms:{
            map: function(doc:any){console.log(doc);emit(doc.uid,doc.total_sms);}.toString(),
            reduce:"_sum"
        },
        sms_by_date:{
            map: function(doc:any){emit(doc.date,doc.total_sms)}.toString(),
            reduce: "_sum"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also initiated:

```
import * as pf from  'pouchdb-find';
PouchDB.plugin(pf);
```

Can any one help me out where the things are wrong and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

All rights folks, I found the issue, dont use typescript for deinfing your design docs.
I created a seperate designs.ts file and put my design in it like this:

```
// @ts-nocheck
export const DES_FOR_ORDERS={
    _id:"_design/for_orders",
    views:{
        find_total_sms:{
            map: function(doc){console.log(doc);emit(doc.uid,doc.total_sms);}.toString(),
            reduce:"_sum"
        },
        sms_by_date:{
            map: function(doc){emit(doc.date,doc.total_sms)}.toString(),
            reduce: "_sum"
        }
    }
}
```

This made it work all good.
Pay attention to `//@ts-nocheck` comment, it will help disable typescript on a particluar file. So I put all my designs in a designs.ts file and used JS inside it to create my design doc.

It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me assigning the map function directly as a string solved it. So I assume the toString()-Method can be problematic here.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.